# How to match original password with encrypted password entry in database on login

Tags: java, database, passwords, md5, password-encryption

```
   MessageDigest alg = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
   alg.reset(); 
   alg.update(password.getBytes());
   byte[] digest = alg.digest();
   StringBuffer hashedpasswd = new StringBuffer();
   String hx;
   for (int i=0;i<digest.length;i++){
   hx =  Integer.toHexString(0xFF & digest[i]);
   //0x03 is equal to 0x3, but we need 0x03 for our md5sum
   if(hx.length() == 1){hx = "0" + hx;}
   hashedpasswd.append(hx);
  }
```

I followed the above code for password encryption. But when login the password checks with database password and login fails as the db entry is encrypted password. How will i check the database's encrypted password with original password on login?

Comment: The pattern to follow here is that your one-way hash the incoming password, and store that in the database table.  Then, you take every incoming clear text password, and also hash it, before comparing against what is stored in the database.

Comment: Encrypt the password with the same algorithm and check with database no need to Decrypt

Comment: So same code should i add in my login page?

Answer (score 5):

While checking with the database, Hash the password you entered with the same algorithm as the one you used to save it in the Data Base. That's how Hashing works. You don't need to "Decrypt" the password from the database, that's not possible. You would rather want to Hash the password you're entering and check whether both the hash values (i.e. the one in db and the one you just hashed) are equal. That is the entire concept of hashing. You can't "DeHash" something. You can only hash the coming data and compare it with previously hashed value.

Comment: So Should i add the same code in login page and compare the hash values by entering the password for eg:admin123.

Comment: Yes, that's what you should do. It would be a little easier if your login logic is in the same language as your back end code.

Comment: I am using jsp for view and java code for the other features.

Comment: I am not much familiar with JSP, 
but where exactly are you comparing the entered value with the value in Data Base? Is it in java or JSP?
By the way, you will have to hash it again during login in any one of them that is for sure.

Comment: The same above posted code i have to add in my login page? The actual password is **gayuranimini** and the db entry is **10171272fc03e05d96c967c88b6b181f**. When i try login the password I am entering is **gayuranimini** which checks with the db entry and fails.

Comment: I am checking the value in java `if(userName.equals(userNameDB) && password.equals(passwordDB))
  {
   System.out.println(password);
     return "SUCCESS"; ////If the user entered values are already present in database, which means user has already registered so I will return SUCCESS message.
  }`

Comment: Before comparing password.equals(passwordDB), do the same thing with passwordDB which should return hashedpassword. and then do (password.equals(hashedpassword)) or what ever logic you have used in your code to hash it.

Comment: `if(userName.equals(userNameDB) && password.equals(passwordDB))` Instead of password I changed to `if(userName.equals(userNameDB) && hashedpasswd.toString().equals(passwordDB))`. And now it works. Thanks for the help @Rohan Shah

Answer (score -1):

encrypt(user_entered_password) == getPasswordFromDatabase()